# Ineffective stack management and registers allocation

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, cortex-m, thumb

Consider the following code:

```
extern unsigned int foo(char c, char **p, unsigned int *n);

unsigned int test(const char *s, char **p, unsigned int *n) 
{
        unsigned int done = 0;

        while (*s)
                done += foo(*s++, p, n); 

        return done;
}
```

Output in Assembly:

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   b5f8        push    {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   2:   0005        movs    r5, r0
   4:   000e        movs    r6, r1
   6:   0017        movs    r7, r2
   8:   2400        movs    r4, #0
   a:   7828        ldrb    r0, [r5, #0]
   c:   2800        cmp r0, #0
   e:   d101        bne.n   14 <test+0x14>
  10:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  12:   bdf8        pop {r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
  14:   003a        movs    r2, r7
  16:   0031        movs    r1, r6
  18:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <foo>
  1c:   3501        adds    r5, #1
  1e:   1824        adds    r4, r4, r0
  20:   e7f3        b.n a <test+0xa>
```

C code compiled using **arm-none-eabi-gcc** versions: 4.9.1, 5.4.0, 6.3.0 and 7.1.0 on
Linux host. Assembly output is the same for all GCC versions.

**CFLAGS := -Os -march=armv6-m -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb**

My understanding of the execution flow is following:

1. Push R3-R7 + LR onto the stack (totally unclear)
2. Move R0 to R5 (this is clear)
3. Move R1 to R6 and R2 to R7 (totally unclear)
4. Dereference R5 into R0 (This is clear)
5. Compare R0 with 0 (This is clear)
6. If R0 != 0 go to line 14: - Restore R1 from R6 and R2 from R7 and call foo(),
   If R0 == 0 stay at line 10, restore R3 - R7 + PC from stack (totally unclear)
7. Increment R5 (clear)
8. accumulate result from foo() (clear)
9. Branch back to line a: (clear)

My own Assembly. Not extensively tested, but definitely I would not need more than R4 + LR to be pushed onto the stack:

**EDIT: According to the provided answers, my example from below will fail due to R1 and R2 not being persistent through call to foo()**

```
51 unsigned int __attribute__((naked)) test_asm(const char *s, char **p, unsigned int *n)
52 {
53         // r0 - *s (move ptr to r3 and dereference it to r0)
54         // r1 - **p
55         // r2 - *n
56         asm volatile(
57                 "   push {r4, lr}               \n\t"
58                 "   movs r4, #0                 \n\t"
59                 "   movs r3, r0                 \n\t"
60                 "1:                             \n\t"
61                 "   ldrb r0, [r3, #0]           \n\t"
62                 "   cmp r0, #0                  \n\t"
63                 "   beq 2f                      \n\t"
64                 "   bl foo                      \n\t"
65                 "   add r4, r4, r0              \n\t"
66                 "   add r3, #1                  \n\t"
67                 "   b 1b                        \n\t"
68                 "2:                             \n\t"
69                 "   movs r0, r4                 \n\t"
70                 "   pop {r4, pc}                \n\t"
71         );
72 }
```

**Questions:**

1. Why GCC stores so many registers for such trivial function?
2. Why it pushes R3 while it is written in ABI that R0-R3 are argument registers
   and supposed to be a caller save and should be safely used inside called function
   in this case test()
3. Why it copy R1 to R6 and R2 to R7 while the prototype of extern function almost
   ideally matches the test() function. So R1 and R2 are already ready to be passed
   to foo() routine. My understanding is that only R0 need to be dereferenced before
   call to foo()

Comment: R0-R3 aren't callee saved, which means the call to `foo`/`fputc` can modify these registers. Since R1 and R2 can be modified the function saves the arguments they contained in R6 and R7, which are callee saved. All of R4, R5, R6 and R7 are modified by the function so need to be saved because these registers are all callee-saved. R3 doesn't need to be saved, so I don't know why its saved on the stack. It might be for alignment reasons.

Comment: Sorry not a callee-save but caller save in this case function on top of test() one. I still can see no reason to copy R1 and R2, foo() should be transparent in example. The result from foo() - argument1 and argument2 should be treated as a return argument of test() for it's top caller. Especially if you go through the assembly listening the R1 and R2 are even restored before entering to foo(). Or I'm wrong, am I?

Comment: As a I said, `foo` can modify R1 and R2. The function `foo` doesn't need to preserve these registers across the call and neither does `test` either. The second and subsequent times `foo` is called the values passed as arguments to `test` are not guaranteed to still be in R1 and R2. Even if `foo` doesn't actually change R1 and R2 the compiler has no way of knowing this and so has to assume it will.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I've just posted my answer that also applies for your last comment under @Johan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. LR must be saved since `test` is not a leaf function. `r5-r7` are used by the function to store values that are used across function calls and since they are not scratch they must be saved. `r3` is pushed to align the stack.
2. Adding an extra register to `push` is a fast and compact way to align the stack.
3. `r1` and `r2` may be trashed by the call to `foo` and since the values initially stored in these registers are needed after the call they must be stored in a location that survive calls.

Comment: LR to store and 8-Byte stack alignment is obvious and outside the question scope. Your point no.3 explains me my doubts. Apparently I was wrongly convinced that if I pass pointers through R0-R3 they should not be changed inside.

Comment: You have three pass by reference variables that need to be preserved beyond the nested call, you have a local variable as well that needs to be preserved so four stack items there, then the return address and in this case alignment (had you one fewer variable, I bet gcc will then burn two stack locations due to lack of optimization, and then you would have an interesting question).  So the reason why it puts so many things on the stack is that you asked it to with having so many variables.

Comment: the arm gcc backend prefers to save the registers on the stack and use them in the function rather than save the variables on the stack and reference them from the stack (ARM is not CISC so this makes sense).